# How to read a line by command line in Swift?

Tags: swift

When creating a variable and giving it a value by command using the function `readLine()`, if you give a number, that number is not an int, is a `String?`. How do you convert this `String?` to an int and put that int into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = readLine()

if let string = input {
  var optionalInt = Int(string)
  if let int = optionalInt {
    print(int)
    // Here you have your int value
  }
}
```

or (unsafe solution):

```
var input = readLine()!
var int = Int(input)!
```

Comment:  if the input is not a valid integer

Comment: Thank so much. The exclamation symbol was the missing piece. Te hago un monumento.

Comment: @MartinR you are right, I have removed the force unwrapping.

Comment: @Leo I have posted a much safer solution. You can try this new code.